# Sorting in NatTables

Tags: nattable, glazedlists

I have got implemented filtering in nattables. How to add sorting? do I have to create new `columnHeaderLayer`? Here is my code:

1 class `BodyLayerStack`

```
class BodyLayerStack extends AbstractLayerTransform {

  private final FilterList<TableLine> filterList;
  private final SelectionLayer selectionLayer;
  private final DataLayer bodyDataLayer;
  private final IRowDataProvider<TableLine> bodyDataProvider;
  private final SortedList<TableLine> sortedList;
  public DataLayer getBodyDataLayer() {
    return bodyDataLayer;
  }
  public SelectionLayer getSelectionLayer() {
    return selectionLayer;
  }
  public IRowDataProvider<TableLine> getBodyDataProvider() {
    return bodyDataProvider;
  }
```

getting values from tables:

```
  public BodyLayerStack(List<TableLine> values, IColumnAccessor<TableLine> columnAccessor, Integer[] columnIndicesForRowHeaders) {
      EventList<TableLine> eventList = GlazedLists.eventList(values);
      TransformedList<TableLine, TableLine> rowObjectsGlazedList = GlazedLists.threadSafeList(eventList);
```

creating filter and sorted list:

```
      this.filterList = new FilterList<>(rowObjectsGlazedList);
      this.sortedList = new SortedList<>(filterList, null);
      this.bodyDataProvider = new ListDataProvider<TableLine>(this.sortedList, columnAccessor);
      bodyDataLayer = new DataLayer(this.bodyDataProvider);
      ColumnOverrideLabelAccumulator bodyLabelAccumulator = new ColumnOverrideLabelAccumulator(bodyDataLayer);
      bodyDataLayer.setConfigLabelAccumulator(bodyLabelAccumulator);

      if( columnIndicesForRowHeaders != null ) {
        for ( int i = 0; i < columnIndicesForRowHeaders.length; i++ ) {
          bodyLabelAccumulator.registerColumnOverrides(
            columnIndicesForRowHeaders[i],
            RowHeaderLabel);
        }
      }
```

event layer:

```
      GlazedListsEventLayer<TableLine> glazedListsEventLayer =
            new GlazedListsEventLayer<>(bodyDataLayer, this.filterList);

      this.selectionLayer = new SelectionLayer(glazedListsEventLayer, false);
      selectionLayer.setSelectionModel(new RowSelectionModel<TableLine>(selectionLayer, this.bodyDataProvider, new IRowIdAccessor<TableLine>()
      {
        @Override
        public Serializable getRowId(TableLine line)
        {
          return line.getId();
        }
      }));
```

adding configuration to selection layer

```
      selectionLayer.addConfiguration(new DefaultSelectionLayerConfiguration()
      {
        @Override
        protected void addSelectionUIBindings()
        {
          addConfiguration(new SelectionBindings());
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        @Override
        protected void addMoveSelectionConfig()
        {
          addConfiguration(new RowOnlySelectionConfiguration());
        }
      });
```

viewport layer + return

```
      ViewportLayer viewportLayer = new ViewportLayer(selectionLayer);
      setUnderlyingLayer(viewportLayer);
  }

  public FilterList<TableLine> getFilterList() {
      return this.filterList;
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add sorting by click on column header cells, you have to add the `SortHeaderLayer` to your column header layer stack.

Please check the [NatTable examples](https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/documentation.php?page=examples_application), like for example the [SortableFilterableColumnGroupExample](https://github.com/eclipse/nebula.widgets.nattable/blob/master/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.examples/src/org/eclipse/nebula/widgets/nattable/examples/_800_Integration/_807_SortableFilterableColumnGroupExample.java)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In that example is `SortHeaderLayer<ExtendedPersonWithAddress> sortHeaderLayer = new SortHeaderLayer<>` and with the same parameter is created new `BodyLayerStack`. But which parameter to use, if I crete it without parameters?: 

`BodyLayerStack bodyLayerStack = new BodyLayerStack( tLines, new LineDataProviderColumnAccessor(propertyNames[0].length), params.getColumnIndicesForRowHeaders());`

Comment: The BodyLayerStack needs to know the underlying data list. The SortHeaderLayer needs the reference to the SortedList from the BodyLayerStack to be able to perform the sort operation. I hope that answers the question, as I am not sure what you have really asked.

Comment: I think, I implemented `SortHeaderLayer` well. So what initialize actual sorting after click on any header? @Dirk Fauth

Comment: The sort bindings. By default only with an additional modifier on click (ALT or STRG) otherwise use the `SingleClickSortConfiguration`.